# Why function returns wrong color in canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas, colors

My canvas color is 50 255 50 155. When I do a code:

`function getClickedAreaColor(x, y) {
        var data = ctx.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data,
            color = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            color.push(data[i]);
        }
        return color;
    }`

It returns 49 255 49 155
Why is that?

Comment: Red Green Blue Alpha?

Comment: how did you paint it? Here it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/jtav1dm6/

Comment: In your example data returned 50 255 50 255, instead of 50, 255, 50, 155

Comment: And that function only returns wronc color, when the Alpha in canvas color is lower than 255.

Comment: my bad, the alpha channel should be decimal, I changed it and now I can see the issue, but it's something expected by the specs

Comment: Rq : in your function, by returning 'data' directly, you'll save a few useless lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a note in the [specs for the getImageData method](http://www.w3.org/TR/2dcontext/#dom-context-2d-getimagedata) for such situations:

> Due to the lossy nature of converting to and from premultiplied alpha
>   color values, pixels that have just been set using putImageData()
>   might be returned to an equivalent getImageData() as different values.

It can explain why you see such difference in

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle="rgba(50, 255, 50, 0.607843137254902)"
ctx.rect(0, 0, 100, 100);
ctx.fill();

console.log(ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 1, 1).data);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jtav1dm6/2/